# Conversão de VARCHAR para INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando fazer INNER JOIN mas os campos  são em VARCHAR.

Em um campo eu tenho **cod_autorizacao** = 749831164

E no outro campo eu tenho **num_aut** = 000749831164

Por causa dos zeros a "**Esquerda**" a ligação não funciona.

Pensei em converte-los para **INT** mas não está dando certo,
Acredito qu seja algum erro de sintaxe.

```
SELECT 

controle.num_aut,estoque.cod_autorizacao 

FROM cad_controle AS controle
INNER JOIN estoque AS estoque WITH(NOLOCK) ON CAST(estoque.cod_autorizacao AS INT)=CAST(controle.num_aut AS INT)
```

Erro que aparece:

```
The conversion of the varchar value '9977613700' overflowed an int column.
```

Comment: O ideal seria comparar tudo como varchar mesmo, `num_aut` é de tamanho fixo? por exemplo sempre tem 10 dígitos, `12345` vira `0000012345`

Comment: Talvez bigint. A mensagem de erro diz que o número é muito grande para o tipo int.

Comment: @rray os 2 campos são varchar(50)

Comment: @bfavaretto tentei converter para bigint e  
Apareceu este erro: Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Comment: @ShaolinFantastic Esse erro deve estar aparecendo provavelmente porque a coluna possuí algum valor que não é numérico.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo porque você está convertendo um valor que não se encaixa no tipo `INT`, aí acaba dando `overflow` na conversão. No `SQL Server`, existem 4 tipos de variáveis para se tratar números inteiros, são eles: `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `INT` e `BIGINT`.

> Abaixo, segue os valores máximos suportados por esses tipos:
>
> - **TINYINT**: 0 à 255.
> - **SMALLINT**: -32,768 à 32,767.
> - **INT**: -2,147,483,648 à 2,147,483,647
> - **BIGINT**: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 à 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Sendo assim, para solucionar seu problema, tenta executar a `QUERY` assim:

```
    SELECT
           controle.num_aut ,
           estoque.cod_autorizacao 
      FROM cad_controle AS controle
INNER JOIN estoque AS estoque WITH ( NOLOCK )
        ON CONVERT ( BIGINT , estoque.cod_autorizacao ) = CONVERT ( BIGINT , controle.num_aut )
```

---

**Edição:**

Ao executar a consulta, caso você se depare com essa mensagem de erro: *`"Error converting data type varchar to bigin"`*, então provavelmente existe um valor `não numérico` em alguma das colunas, para resolver esse caso, tenta executar a consulta abaixo, para corrigir esse problema, só que dessa forma, **`talvez`** seu `INNER JOIN` não funcione da forma que você queira.

```
    SELECT
           controle.num_aut ,
           estoque.cod_autorizacao 
      FROM cad_controle AS controle
INNER JOIN estoque AS estoque WITH ( NOLOCK )
        ON 
           ( CASE WHEN ( ISNUMERIC ( estoque.cod_autorizacao ) = 1 ) THEN CONVERT ( BIGINT , estoque.cod_autorizacao ) ELSE 0 END ) =
           ( CASE WHEN ( ISNUMERIC ( controle.num_aut ) = 1 ) THEN CONVERT ( BIGINT , controle.num_aut ) ELSE 0 END )
```

Comment: Apareceu este erro: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: @ShaolinFantastic eu dei uma editada na resposta, para que outros possam compreender melhor o porque o seu erro estava ocorrendo, e modifiquei também a consulta, tenta com essa nova query da edição.

Comment: @ShaolinFantastic postei uma nova `QUERY` que talvez resolva seu problema com a conversão do `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Cara gostei muito da sua solução mas to começando a achar que é algum problema de versão pois continua trazendo o Erro:Error converting data type varchar to bigint. Eu uso o SQL SERVER 2016

Comment: @ShaolinFantastic estou testando em um Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (Intel X86) e a segunda consulta (utilizando o `CASE`) funciona, acho muito difícil ter mudado algo em relação a isso.

Comment: Deu certo! eu não tinha colocado o "CASE" Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ah que ótimo @ShaolinFantastic! Só faça alguns testes e tenha certeza que não vai haver problemas com o seu `INNER JOIN` devido o `CASE` retornar 0.

Comment: Com a consulta a seguir, você descobre quais linhas possuem problemas: `SELECT controle.num_aut , estoque.cod_autorizacao FROM cad_controle AS controle WHERE ISNUMERIC ( estoque.cod_autorizacao ) = 0 OR ISNUMERIC ( estoque.cod_autorizacao ) = 0`