# Como converter um campo VARCHAR(30) COM CARACTERES ESPECIAIS PARA NUMERO?

Tags: banco-de-dados, int, varchar, sql-server-2005

Estou com uma dúvida aparentemente simples, porém estou quebrando a cabeça a algumas horas, por isso decidi pedir ajuda.

Ao executar a consulta abaixo a mesma executa normalmente.

```
Select campo1, campo2 from tabela;
```

Tive o seguinte resultado:

```
campo 1 = 296998.00 ("sempre um numero")
campo 2 = 2,5       (Vários resultados, compostos por caráteres especiais, "%", ",", "Letras" e etc..
```

Quero simplesmente fazer o `campo1 * campo2` gerando um terceiro campo resultado da operação.

```
Select campo1, campo2, (campo1 * campo2) as vlr_taxa from tabela;
```

Entretanto essa consulta retorna o seguinte erro:

> Mensagem 8114, Nível 16, Estado 5, Linha 2 Error converting data type
>   varchar to numeric.

Pesquisei bastante na internet e aqui na comunidade, porém não achei uma solução simples para o caso.

Segue publicações que já vi, mas que não resolveram meu problema.

[CAST e CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[Conversão de VARCHAR para INT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219869/convers%C3%A3o-de-varchar-para-int)

Comment: Pode passar uma lista de dados que tenham nos `campo1` e `campo2`?

Comment: Obrigado pelo intersere em ajudar. Estou anexando um Excel com 100 linhas que extrai do banco.

Comment: Segue link para o arquivo - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1edbyqHPe0h5DnSOIROJwSWzUAKYTtEwV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Pelo que vi os dados das colunas, você terá que fazer alguns `replace` (por exemplo, removendo a `%`), para normalizar os dados, ou seja, deixar em uma mesmo padrão, ai então fazer a mudança conforme sugerido pelo Ronaldo. Recomendo fortemente voce tipar essa coluna como `decimal`, para não acontece rmais isso e nnem precisar de conversões.

Comment: Novamente obrigado pelo retorno, sou iniciante e meio que preciso ver desenhado para entender. Teria algum exemplo de como eu poderia usar o replace para esta função?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que os separadores decimais do campo estejam na mesma cultura que você está trabalhando, esse comando converte o varchar em numérico

```
select cast(campo1 as float) * cast(campo2 as float) as vlr_taxa from tabela
```

Caso contrário será necessário garantir isso (através de `replace` por exemplo)

Comment: Ronaldo, fiz o teste que você pediu porem sem sucesso. "Mensagem 8114, Nível 16, Estado 5, Linha 1 Error converting data type varchar to float"

Comment: O valor desse varchar está usando o que como delimitador decimal? Vírgula ou ponto?

Comment: Ronaldo, pelo que avaliei o sistema onde os usuários realizam o inserção dos dados  não esta tratando os dados inseridos, ficou meio bagunçado. Ex: tem campos com " ", "%", "texto" e etc, pelo que avaliei a maioria dos registros estão com o delimitador "," . Vou ter que avaliar uma forma de remover os caracteres especiais e depois converter para numero e conseguir realizar o calculo.

Comment: Entendi.
Se fosse só o caractere diferente, um ou dois `Replace`s seriam suficiente. Mas por ser uma grande variedade de diferenças, precisa analisar de acordo com o que aparece. Edite a pergunta informando quais as possíveis entradas para essa coluna.

Comment: Ronaldo achei essa publicação, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string só não entendi se a mesma pode me atender.

Comment: Caso precise de algo no SQL, confire [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)